# How can I detect when a portal is broken?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am writing a Spigot plugin and want to be notified when a portal is broken for any reason (obsidian frame broken, portal hit by ghast, etc)

There is the `BlockBreakEvent` but this is only called for the obsidian block, not the portal.

There is also `BlockPhysicsEvent`, but this gets called at other times - for example, if a fire is lit directly in front of a portal.

Comment: I don't use bukkit, or even play MineCraft. But, based on the Spigot API, it seems you'll want to listen for [`PortalCreateEvent`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/world/PortalCreateEvent.html), maintain a reference to [`blocks`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/world/PortalCreateEvent.html#getBlocks--), then check if any blocks from a `BlockBreakEvent` are contained in the list of portal blocks.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Nice idea! Would you mind adding this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @VinceEmigh's answer won't be enough... You also have to check for EntityExplodeEvent since Fireballs of Ghasts can also blow out a portal.

Comment: Another problem is that `PortalCreateEvent` only gets run if a portal is created by hand and not when creating the counterpart of the portal in the nether/overworld.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're looking for `BlockPhysicsEvent`. It shouldn't matter if a fire is lit in front of the portal as you're you're cancelling the event on the portal block, not the event on the block that was set on fire.

```java
@EventHandler
public void onBlockPhysics(BlockPhysicsEvent event) {
    if(event.getChangedType() == Material.PORTAL || event.getBlock().getType() == Material.PORTAL) {
        event.setCancelled();
    }
}
```